# Problems running python script by windows task scheduler that does pscp

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scp

Not sure if anyone has run into this, but I'll take suggestions for troubleshooting and/or alternative methods.

I have a Windows 2008 server on which I am running several scheduled tasks.  One of those tasks is a python script that uses pscp to log into a linux box, checks for new files and if there is anything new, copies them down to a local directory on the C: drive.  I've put some logging into the script at key points as well and I'm using `logging.basicConfig(level=DEBUG)`.

I built the command using a variable, `command = 'pscp -pw xxxx name@ip:/ c:\local_dir'` and then I use `subprocess.call(command)` to execute the command.

Now here's the weird part.  If I run the script manually from the command line, it works fine.  New files are downloaded and processed.  However, if the Task Scheduler runs the script, no new files are downloaded.  The script is running under the same user, but yet yields different results.

According to the log files created by the script and on the linux box, the script successfully logs into the linux box.  However, no files are downloaded despite there being new files.  Again, when I run it via the command line, files are downloaded.

Any ideas? suggestions, alternative methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for these answers. It turns out both of you are right.  Task Scheduler is weird in two ways:  First; it doesn't like mapped drives.  It works fine with UNC references.  Second; it likes a full path reference for everything. Files, commands, syntax within scripts, everything.  In fact, using these two techniques is how I fixed my problem.    Now my only problem is deciding which answer to click correct since both work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue when trying to open an MS Access database on a Linux VM. Running the script at the Windows 7 command prompt worked but running it in Task Scheduler didn't. With Task Scheduler it would find the database and verify it existed but wouldn't return the tables within it.

The solution was to have Task Scheduler run **cmd** as the Program/Script with the arguments **/c python C:\path\to\script.py** (under Add arguments (optional)).

I can't tell you why this works but it solved my problem.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either.  every thing I try, it does nothing when I press Run.  >:(

Comment: How do I prevent annoying "taskeng.exe" window from popping up every time script is executed (my script runs every 15 mins)?

Answer (score 23):

You can use the windows Task Scheduler, but make sure the "optional" field "Start In" is filled in.

In the Task Scheduler app, add an action that specifies your python file to run "doSomeWork" and fill in the Start in (optional) input with the directory that contains the file.. So for example if you have a python file in:

```
C:\pythonProject\doSomeWork.py
```

You would enter:

```
Program/Script: doSomeWork.py

Start in (optional): C:\pythonProject
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: @jax Thanks. This was what worked best for me so I decided to post

Comment: @ErkinDjindjiev, I tried the above method but the script is not running. But it works correctly when i run the same in command prompt

Answer (score 5):

I'm having a similar issue. In testing I found that any type of call with subprocess stops the python script when run in task scheduler but works fine when run on the command line.

```
import subprocess

print('Start')
test = subprocess.check_output(["dir"], shell=True)
print('First call finished')
```

When run on command line this outputs:

```
Start
First call finished
```

When run from task scheduler the output is:

```
Start
```

In order to get the output from task scheduler I run the python script from a batch file as follows:

```
python test.py >> log.txt
```

I run the script through the batch file both on command line and through task scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Brad's answer is right. Subprocess needs the shell context to work and the task manager can launch python without that. Another way to do it is to make a batch file that is launched by the task scheduler that calls python c:\path\to\script.py etc. The only difference to this is that if you run into a script that has a call to os.getcwd() you will always get the root where the script is but you get something else when you make the call to cmd from task scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

**Last edit - start**

After experiments... If you put there full path to python program it works without highest privileges (as admin). Meaning task settings like this:

```
program: "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe"
arguments: "D:\folder\folder\python script.py"
```

I have no idea why, but it works even if script uses subprocess and multiple threads.

**Last edit - end**

What I did is I changed task settings: checked `Run with highest privileges`. And task started to work perfectly while running `python [script path]`.
But keep in mind, that title contains "Administrator: " at the begining... always...

P.S. Thanks guys for pointing out that subprocess is a problem. It made me think of task settings.
I had similar problem when one script is running from Windows Task Scheduler, and another one doesn't.
Running cmd with `python [script path]` didn't work for me on Windows 8.1 Embedded x64. Not sure why. Probably because of necessity to have spaces in path and issue with quotes.
Hope my answer helps someone. ;)

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: I was using the batch file (.bat) approach and having issues with sub-processes being killed. This fixed the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file add your python script in your batch file and then schedule that batch file .it will work .
Example : suppose your python script is in folder   c:\abhishek\script\merun.py
first you have to go to directory by cd command .so your batch file would be like :

cd c:\abhishek\script
python merun.py

it work for me .

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this for posterity: A similar issue I faced was resolved by using the UNC (\10.x.xx.xx\Folder\xxx)path everywhere in my .bat and .py scripts instead of the letter assigned to the drive (\K:\Folder\xxx).

Comment: Correct. The default user that executes the task scheduler action is not aware there are mapped drives as they are specific to the logged in user. You can add `net use S: "\\server\path"` in a script beforehand to keep the letter mappings consistent in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before. I was able to run the task manually in Windows Task Scheduler, but not automatically. I remembered that there was a change in the time made by another user, maybe this change made the task scheduler to error out. I am not sure. Therefore, I created another task with a different name, for the same script, and the script worked automatically. Try to create a test task running the same script. Hopefully that works!

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda installation of python in windows below solution worked for me

1. create a batch file with below
   "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\condabin\activate" && python "script.py" &&
   deactivate
2. Setup task to run this batch file