# Scheduled scripts stopped logging correctly...don't understand cause

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I have a few python scripts that I run with Task Scheduler (Windows 10) everyday. When the scripts run I have a few print lines that I like to view in the command prompt to see some information regarding the script as it runs.

I actually had the scripts printing out until recently when I changed the directory path.

I have "**Run whether user is logged on or not**" chosen, along with "**Run with highest privileges**". I also haven chosen "**Configure for: Windows 10**"

For Program/script: `C:\Python27\python.exe`

Add arguments:

```
C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Quant\chron_scripts\obtainPriceData.py >> log.txt
```

I previously had the script in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Quant\obtainPriceData.py >> log.txt
```

This worked fine. It is only when I added the chron_scripts directory that nothing gets logged on the command prompt. Any suggestions would be much apperciated, and thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "log on the command prompt" ?  Are you expecting to see the log statements in a file, or in a command window?

Comment: Does `log.txt` exist in the new directory?  `>>` might not create the file if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: John - No serious logging, Just Print statements in a command window, and there is no log.txt files.  I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196049/problems-running-python-script-by-windows-task-scheduler-that-does-pscp which worked, in my first case. The command prompt would show the print statements, and after the script finished executing, the log.txt file would delete itself

Comment: Try creating a blank `log.txt` file in the new directory.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but previously when the task triggered it would just pop up a command window, display any print statements as the script ran, then after the script completed the command window closed itself.

Comment: So the print statements never went into the log file, even in the previous directory?

Comment: Correct, nothing was saved off into a directory. It was just a window that basically showed the script run as if you were running it from the command line yourself. After the script completed it terminated the command window. Also the python scripts still run, and do what they are suppose to (I checked the database), they just no longer print out information

Comment: It sounds like the output is now getting saved in `log.txt` as you originally intended; the question is, where is that file located?  When you set up the job with Task Scheduler, did you specify a working directory?  If so, look there for `log.txt`; otherwise try looking in `C:\Python27`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your log file is in other directories such as the working directory. Maybe try to specify the location of log.txt can solve your problem